# Tridion Access Management Azure User mapping with existing groups

Tags: sdl-tridion, sites-9.5, access-management, users

We have Installed Access Management Successfully, After that when we login we are able to Login to Tridion Sites 9.5 with azure:emailid earlier we created users with Corp/EmployeeId
Now we have 2 accounts, How can we map the existing group mapping available in "member of" tab to the new user id.

As per documentation, we have executed **Update-TcmGroupMappingsToAccessManagement** still issue has not been resolved.

Can you please help?

Comment: What are you migrating from? Legacy LDAP integration? Did you configure Directory Group Mappings before?